# Azure-Policy-Modify json to remove tag value

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I want to be able to enfore the creation of tag names with new resource groups but allow the creator of the resource group to specify the value. This is a policy definition with both name and value. I tried to remove value, but it didn't like it. Is there a way to do this, where the policy definition enforces the name only?

```html
 "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value on resource groups",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value on resource groups.",
      "mode": "All",
      "parameters": {
         "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
            }
         },
         "tagValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as headquarter"
            }
         }
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
            "allOf": [
               {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
               },
               {
                  "not": {
                     "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                     "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   }
}

Changed to remove value:
{
    "properties": {
       "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value on resource groups",
       "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value on resource groups.",
       "mode": "All",
       "parameters": {
          "tagName": {
             "type": "String",
             "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
             }
          }
       },
       "policyRule": {
          "if": {
             "allOf": [
                {
                   "field": "type",
                   "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                },
                {
                   "not": {
                      "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                      }
                }
             ]
          },
          "then": {
             "effect": "deny"
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to enforce the creation of tag names with new resource groups but allow the creator of the resource group to specify the value.

I have used below `Azure Policy` to enforce specific `Tag` names on new `Resource Groups` during creation, but allow any random value for the `Tag` values.

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "tags['Tag1']", // you can add any name here
                    "exists": "true"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "tags['Tag2']", // you can add any name here
                    "exists": "true"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

If the `Tag names` do not meet the condition, resource group creation will be denied. However, you can add any value to the **'Value'** parameter.

**Output:**

[image]

If the `Tag names` match, it allows you to enter any value in the `Value` field.

[image]